# iOS (Swift): Presenting View Controller Embedded in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a `UIViewController` (`AVC`) that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. `AVC` (present modally) segues to another `UIViewController` (`BVC`). Inside `BVC`, the variable `self.presentingViewController` is of type an optional `NavigationController` rather than a `AVC` as I would have expected.

I have to downcast the first `childViewControllers` as an `AVC` as follows:

```
let pvc = self.presentingViewController
if let avc = pvc?.childViewControllers.first as? AVC {
    // ...
}
```

Why is `self.presentingViewController` not as I expected it to, i.e. an `AVC`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access it

```
if let pvc = self.presentingViewController as? UINavigationController {
    if let avc = pvc.viewControllers.first as? AVC {
       // ...
    }
}
```

//

**[From Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller)**

> When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or
>   implicitly) using the present(_:animated:completion:) method, the view
>   controller that was presented has this property set to the view
>   controller that presented it. If the view controller was not presented
>   modally, but one of its ancestors was, this property contains the view
>   controller that presented the ancestor. If neither the current view
>   controller or any of its ancestors were presented modally, the value
>   in this property is nil.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my question is **why**? Why is `presentingViewController` not of type `AV`?

Comment: Okay - so I present `BVC` modally from `AVC`. So why is this property of type `NavigationController` rather than `AVC`?

Comment: Because AVC is not presented modally  , see if you tried to present a VC say it's name is CVC from BVC , then self.presentingViewController of CVC will be BVC as BVC is presented modally ,,